# MySQL User defined function - an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I tried with various version but I am getting the same error message while creating user define functions like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION avg_month(shop INT) RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
DECLARE
    avg_m_sales DECIMAL;
SET
    avg_m_sales = 1000; 
RETURN avg_m_sales;
END;
```

The error message is:

**Error**
SQL query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION avg_month(shop INT) RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
DECLARE
    avg_m_sales DECIMAL
```

MySQL said: Documentation

**1064** - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delimiters other than the default  ; are typically used when defining functions, stored procedures, and triggers wherein you must define multiple statements.

Try to create below way.
"testdb" is you database name.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE

    FUNCTION `testdb`.`avg_month`(shop INT)
    RETURNS DECIMAL

    BEGIN
DECLARE
    avg_m_sales DECIMAL;
SET
    avg_m_sales = 1000; 
RETURN avg_m_sales;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: some explanation of why this works would help anyone else visiting this question.